# Visualforce conditionally include script file

Tags: visualforce

We would like to include a visualforce file only if the user is not running lightning 
Tried using this but the syntax is not right.

```
{!IF( $User.UIThemeDisplayed != 'Theme4d',<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.myzip, '/myfile.js')}"/>)}
```

But get the error:
Error: Syntax error. Found '<'
After saving the file.
Does anybody know if this supported and what is the right syntax?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can conditionally render it by using apex:outputText:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed != 'Theme4d'}">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.myzip, '/myfile.js')}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

This will automatically include the appropriate file as necessary.

Comment: outputText instead of outputPanel is because it also works in lightning UI?

Comment: @Rahul There's really not much difference between the two; either will get the job done. I just tend to go with the shorter code.

Comment: using outputPanel with layout="none" would include the script without generating any HTML tags for the panel itself, which might be a bit cleaner for what that's worth.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm

Comment: As Raul mentioned, outputText is a good option. outputPanel adds extra <span> and having the span inside the head tags make your HTML invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Use outputPanel with render condition it will work in all scenario

```
<apex:outputPanel  rendered="{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed != 'Theme4d'}">
```

Thank you
Amol Salve
Salesforce Developer